# Possible bug with load() and parse() methods in PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I tried to use [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) on regular `.pdf` files and it worked fine.

However when I encountered a corrupted `.pdf` , the code would "freeze" .. *not throwing errors or something* .. simply the `load` or `parse` function take forever to execute

Here is [the corrupted file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/MYFILE.zip) (i have zipped it so that everybody could download it), it is probably not a native pdf file but it was saved as a `.pdf` extension and it is only 4 Kb.

I am not an expert at all, but I think that this is a bug with PDFBox. According to documentation, both `load()` and `parse()` methods are supposed to throw exceptions if they fail. However in case with my file, the code would take forever to execute and not throw exception.

I tried using only `load`, one can try `parse()` .. the result is the same

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;

public class TestTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        System.out.println(pdfToText("C:\\..............MYFILE.pdf")); 
        System.out.println("done ! ! !");
    }
    private static String pdfToText(String fileName) throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = null;
        document = PDDocument.load(new File(fileName)); // THIS TAKES FOREVER
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        document.close();
        return stripper.getText(document);
    }
}
```

How to force this code throw an exception or stop executing if the `.pdf` file is corrupted?
Thanks

Comment: Have you used a debugger to step through the listing to determine which lines it can execute before not returning?

Comment: Is it always the same pdf causing the infinite loop? And are you sure it's an infinite loop and not merely some giant pdf taking its time to be parsed?

Comment: no, it is not a giant `.pdf`. I have modified my question. The corrupted pdf file is 14 Kb and when I opened it with a notepad, i realized that that was some html page that was save as a `.pdf`

Comment: Have you tried `loadNonSeq` instead of `load`?

Comment: @mlk `loadNonSeq` is undefined under the type PDDocument

Comment: I tried  `document = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File(fileName));` Eclipse underlined it because it is undefined

Comment: If you use eclipse, you can easily open the class `PDDocument` (F3 when the cursor is on it). In the eclipse outline view you'll see that there are numerous `loadNonSeq` overloads. All of them expect at least two parameters. You might try using a `RandomAccess` parameter value `null`.

Comment: When I use `PDDocument.load(new File(fileName))` with the MYFILE.pdf from your MYFILE.zip (an rtf file actually), I immediately get an `IOException`. Which PDFBox version do you use? I'm using the current 1.8.2.

Comment: @mlk I use `pdfbox-0.8.0-incubating`

Comment: *pdfbox-0.8.0-incubating* - I would propose updating. That version is ancient and very many issues meanwhile have been recognized and fixed. The `loadNonSeq` may have been added later just like the test throwing the `IOException` I get trying to read your sample file.

Comment: Thank you, i updated it and now it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementing simple timeouts for 3rd party libs I often use an implementation like Apache Commons [ThreadMonitor](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/cobertura/org.apache.commons.io.ThreadMonitor.html):

```
long timeoutInMillis = 1000;

try {
    Thread monitor = ThreadMonitor.start(timeoutInMillis);  
    // do some work here
    ThreadMonitor.stop(monitor);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // timed amount was reached
}
```

Example code is from Apache's ThreadMonitor Javadoc.
I only use this when the 3rd party API does not provide some timeout mechanism, of course.

However I was forced to tweak this a bit some weeks ago, because this solution does not work well with (3rd party) code that is using Exception masking.

In particular we run into problems with c3p0 which masks all Exceptions (and in particular `InterruptedException`s). Our solution was to tweak the implementation to also check the exception's cause chain for `InterruptedException`s.

Comment: +1 Thank you i tried this solution and i will implement it in other cases. however, in this particular case. it does not work

Comment: Well, what is not working? What exception do you get? I am not sure you really tried this, because when it really hangs then this should throw InterruptedException when timeout occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
private static String pdfToText(String fileName) {
    PDDocument document = null;
    try {
        document = PDDocument.load(fileName);
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        return stripper.getText(document);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to open PDF Parser. " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (document != null) {
            try {
                document.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I remember, PDFBox allow to validate input file, try to do it before parse: http://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/pdfavalidation.html